# Is this relationship OneToMany or ManyToMany?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, entity-relationship

I have two tables  `ARTICLE` and `FAQ` ( frequently asked questions ). I'm trying to establish a relationship between these two tables but I'm confused!

What I want to achieve is that article can have many FAQ. So for this should I create a pivot table or just reference a `FK` in FAQ table?

What I tried but I'm not sure that the below flow is right or not?

Article table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

FAQ Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `eb_faq` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `faq_category_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `question` text NOT NULL,
  `answer` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Pivot:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article_linked_faq` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `article_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `faq_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Comment: When you design relation you have to think at the direct relation, Article->FAQ but also at the reverse: FAQ->Article. In this way you can tell if it's a OneToMany or a ManyToMany.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This schema will indeed allow an article to have multiple FAQs, but also allows one FAQ to be linked to multiple articles. If that's what you want, great! If not then I'd suggest removing the pivot table and adding article_id into eb_faq.

Comment: Yes we need an option which allow the user to link FAQ to any article!

Answer (score -1):

No, you just need to add foreign key in faq table, it will create the relationship between both tables. There is no need to create a third table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `eb_faq` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `articleId`  int(11),
  `faq_category_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `question` text NOT NULL,
  `answer` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   FOREIGN KEY (articleId) REFERENCES article(id)
);
```